# Testing async method without completion block?

Tags: ios, objective-c, testing

I saw this question asked a few times but the responses they have doesn't really answer the question.

I have a function similar to this:

```objectivec
- (instancetype)initWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        ...
        if ([NSThread isMainThread]) {
            [self loadAttributedText];
        } else {
            @weakify(self);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                @strongify(self);
                [self loadAttributedText];
            });
        }
    }

    return self;
}
```

I do not have to test specifically that function, but I do have to test the value of some class properties that are modified by the function `loadAttributedText`.

The problem I'm facing is that at the time of class allocation, the `loadAttriubutedText` is called an async method, so when I try to make an assertion on the class properties, they are not yet initialized.

I've tried using `XCTestExpectation` but I do not have a completion block in the `initWithDictionary` method and I am not intended to add one to it.

Is there a way to test this? Thanks.

P.S: I'm using OCMock to write the tests.

Comment: What your test cases are showing is that this init is broken. It's a walking race condition unless all other accessors are forwarded to the main queue (and if they were, then your test cases would work). This can't be fixed without fixing the bug. How to fix this bug depends on the rest of code, but likely, every accessor also needs to be routed to the main queue, or the `dispatch_async` needs to be `dispatch_sync` (which can create deadlock, so it depends on what `loadAttributedText` does). It's also possible you need a separate (non-main) queue for this. Depends on the rest of the code.

Comment: I think that initiating asynchronous work from `init` is probably a bit of an anti-pattern.  I would probably use a static/class method that returned the initialised instance via a closure.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [XCTest: Test asyncronous function without completion block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33760116/xctest-test-asyncronous-function-without-completion-block)